# Hide default properties in xaml designer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I created a C# WPF UserControl with the property

```
 public Brush SomeBrush { get; set; }
```

When I drag this control into a window and view it in the XAML editor I see 
'SomeBrush' under 'Others' between many other default properties.

Is it possible to hide every default property in the designer or would I have to override each and add a
`[Browsable(false)]` attribute to them?

Edit: Why do I want to do this? Because not everyone is experienced in Wpf and it's much easier to just see the needed properties instead of all.

Comment: I can't imagine why you would want to go to the effort of doing this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: First of all, delete that. Second, if the brush is used for an everyday usage (such as Foreground or Background color), then use the built-in properties instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Third, if no built-in properties satisfy your requirement, create a DependencyProperty instead of a regular CLR property, so that it can be bound or otherwise used like any other WPF DependencyProperty.

Comment: Fourth: no one really cares about the Visual Studio designer for WPF. Writing XAML manually is soo much faster and easier.

Comment: This is just an example. I have a control which has only 3 properties: BackgroundColor, ForegroundColor and Text and I thought showing the user hundreds of properties which are doing nothing isn't that great.

Comment: @91378246 Sorry, built-in WPF properties don't "do nothing". They are actually useful. If you have those 3 properties you might as well be using a `TextBox`, `TextBlock` or similar text-capable UI element, depending on your needs. I fail to undestand what you're really trying to do but it sounds and looks bad imo.